# Why a undirected graph is Markov equivalent to a directed graph iff it is decomposable?

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network, markov-random-field

Claim 1.

> A undirected graph is Markov equivalent to a directed graph iff the undirected graph is decomposable.

I am trying to prove Claim 1 and to find a relationship between decomposable and v-structure.

I have shown Claim 2:

> A DAG is Markov equivalent to an undirected graph iff it contains no v-structures.

I am given the hint that using Claim 2 to show Claim 1, but I try a lot of ways and fail. Is there another way to show Claim 1 without using Claim 2? Thanks!